# Bootstrap 3 implementation causing large right shift of all elements

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am using AJAX to fill data in a DataTable which is all working correctly. However I need to have a Boostrap Modal popup when I click on the first element.

The triggering was all working correctly, however it did not pop up over my data table. I realized I needed to upgrade to Bootstrap 3.3.7 to fix this. Which worked the Modal works correctly now.

However now all of my elements have been shifted right and I have no idea how to fix it. I have tried permanently setting margins and padding to 0, however this had no change. In Chrome Dev Tools I cannot identify any element causing the spacing.

I deleted all my elements and all my personal CSS and it is still being shifted to the center right.

See here:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PoN6P.jpg

Below is the Script SRC and the stylesheets I am using:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/bootstrap.css">
<script src="~/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>


<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.0.3/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.3/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"> </script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.3/js/buttons.flash.min.js"> </script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/2.5.0/jszip.min.js"> </script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/0.1.18/build/vfs_fonts.js"> </script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.3/js/buttons.html5.min.js"> </script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.3/js/buttons.print.min.js"> </script>


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700,300,100&amp;lang=en">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/1.2.3/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/Site.css">
```

And here is my body CSS:

```
body {
background-color: #FFFFFF;
font-family: "Roboto", helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-weight: 400;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
padding: 0 !important;
margin: 0 !important;
```

}

Here is my View (without Jscript):

```
<body>
<div class="filter">
    <form class="my-form" method="post">
        <br />
        @Html.DropDownList("list", "Select Company")
        <br />
        <br />
        <button input type="submit"> Submit </button>
        <br /><br />
    </form>
</div>

<div id="ck-button">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="active"><span>Active</span>
    </label>
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="inactive"><span>InActive</span>
    </label>
</div>



<div class="scrollingTable">
    <table class="table-fill" id="myTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Stock Id</th>
                <th>Product Group</th>
                <th>Group Type</th>
                <th>Item Type</th>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Serial No</th>
                <th>NR</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>State</th>
                <th>Date Arrived</th>
                <th>Current Location</th>
                <th>Terminal ID</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th class="foot1">Id</th>
                <th class="foot">Product</th>
                <th class="foot">Group</th>
                <th class="foot">Item</th>
                <th class="foot">Model</th>
                <th class="foot">Serial</th>
                <th class="foot">NR</th>
                <th class="foot">Status</th>
                <th class="foot">Descr</th>
                <th class="foot">State</th>
                <th class="foot">Date</th>
                <th class="foot">Location</th>
                <th class="foot3">T-ID</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>


    </table>

</div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to place your code into

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        // code here
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

and see if it works correctly